# Is it possible to make text sticky in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

On my website file I'm trying to display a series of images on the left side of the sight, and have text information on the images stick to the top of the page on the right side. I've tried sticky-top, dataspy="affix", and multiple other things but no dice.

Here is an example of what I mean:
[http://imgur.com/T8Vo0JC](https://imgur.com/T8Vo0JC)

```
   <div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
      <img id="constructedimage" src="images/small1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
      <p class="pstylefooter">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac </p>
   </div>

</div>

  </div>      

  <div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
        <p class="pstyle">PROCESS WORK</p>
      <img id="constructedimage" src="images/small1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If i understand it correct, you want images div scroll down while keeping the text stick to the window, relative to its div position. Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: sticky`

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  margin-left: 50%;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

div {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="sticky">text</p>
  <img id="constructedimage" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/farang/farang1201/farang120100040/11875191-Amazing-sunset-scene-Long-exposure-shot-vertical-panoramic-composition-Stock-Photo.jpg">
</div>

<div>
  <p class="sticky">more text</p>
  <img id="constructedimage" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/farang/farang1201/farang120100040/11875191-Amazing-sunset-scene-Long-exposure-shot-vertical-panoramic-composition-Stock-Photo.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I explained it well, where you have the word text I want that to stay at the top of the page while I scroll through the images on the left.

Comment: @beav910 that's what `position: sticky` does. Your browser probably doesn't support this feature. I don't think anyone is going to code out a custom sticky solution for you without you at least taking a stab at it yourself. You could always use something like [bootstrap affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) to mimic what I did here, that's a prepackaged library for doing the same thing.

Comment: I believe your answer seems reasonable. But I assume that, `More text` which you added to your snippet, may not be wanted after all. That is my guess of course.